# Connectedness of the neighbourhood of a unique minimal point

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a real valued continuous function defined on a compact subset $\Omega$ of $R^n$ and has its minimum $0$ achieved at a unique point say $0$. Is it true that for a sufficiently small positive $\epsilon$, $f^{-1}([0,\epsilon))$ is a simply connected open neighbourhood of $0$ relative to $\Omega$? Is $f^{-1}([0,\epsilon])$ a simply connected closed neighbourhood of $0$ relative to $\Omega$?

Comment: Do you mean neighborhood of $x_m$?

Comment: @WimC: Yes, you are right. I have corrected it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then the function $f$ defined on the interval $[0,1]$  by $$f{: x} \mapsto x + x \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2x}\right)$$ for $x \in (0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$ is a counter example. Note that if $$\varepsilon \in (\frac1{2n+2},\frac1{2n}]$$ and $n \geq 2$ is an integer then $$f\left(\frac1{2n+3} \right)=\frac2{2n+3}>\frac1{2n}\geq \varepsilon > \frac1{2n+2} = f\left(\frac1{2n+2} \right).$$

Comment: You are right. I have thought of examples similar to the second term of your function so that was why I supposed the uniqueness of the minimum point to skirt this problem. The difference is I did not try tilting the function with something like the first term in your function.